# Which gods, or any other character from scriptures, rides on seven horses or steers a seven-horse chariot?

Tags: gods

Which God or any Character from scriptures ride on seven horse or seven horse chariot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Which God or any Character from scriptures ride on seven horse or seven horse chariot?

Lord surya.

> Rigved 1:50:8 Seven horses Steeds harnessed to thy car bear thee, O thou farseeing One,God, Sūrya, with the radiant hair.

Comment: Are there any other God?

Comment: No.In Hinduism each God has unique vehicle @Hindukid